# Try GetElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, classname

try js ref_doc_getelementsbyClassName

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null "

This **HTML** code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" class="test"  />
```

This **JS** code

```
function inputtest() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test').value = selectedControl;
}
```

Comment: change `document.getElementsByClassName('test')` to `document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0]`
 because selecting with class name returns in array

Comment: You can NOT have two class types defined in one `input`. -  add `test` with the same class as `form-control` - like this => `class="form-control test"`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` gives an array not an object. try `document.getElementsByClassName('test') && document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].value = selectedControl`

Comment: I try this but The same ..
document.getElementsByClassName('test') && document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].value = selectedControl

Comment: OK here is the thing first of all merge your classes like `class="form-control test"` and use CSS selector like `querySelector('.test').value = selectedControl` but this `document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].value = selectedControl`  seems to work to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control test"  />
```

JS

```
function inputtest() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].value = selectedControl;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as it is

Comment: Okay. I am sorry. But just now I saw the comment section and got to know that your problem has been solved

Comment: don't worry .. thanks

Comment: So it worked out for you or not?

Comment: Yesssss , worked  :)